# Compactness of operators and norming sets

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, compact-operators

Let $T$ be a linear map from a normed space $E$ into a Banach space $F$.

Let $D\subset \overline{B}_{F^{*}}$ be norming, i.e. there is $r>0$ such that $\sup_D|\left<f,v\right>|\ge r\|f\|$, for every $f\in F$.

It is easy to see that a linear map $T:E\to F$ is bounded iff $T^{*}D$ is bounded.

If $T$ is (weakly) compact, then $T^{*}$ is a (weakly) compact, and then $T^{*}D$ is relatively (weakly) compact.

> I am wondering about the converse of the last statement.

I can show that compactness of $T$ follows from relative compactness of $T^{*}D$ under the assumption that $E^{*}$ is separable, but no progress whatsoever about the weak compactness.